# Sonar database

Tags: database, sonarqube

In sonar by which algorithm the folders and files are stored in the "projects" table.
which are the files using to store these datas to "projects" table.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not analyse the Sonar database schema too much (unless you plan to be a Sonar developer).

The best (and recommended way) to interact with Sonar is via the published [REST API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API)

Comment: Exactly. The (simple) reason is that the db schema is subject for change where as the REST API stays as much as compatible with previous versions.